# hangparas environment (hanging package) only works for the first paragraph

Tags: pdftex, luatex

Here is my sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}
\begin{document}

\newpage
\begin{center}
Works Cited
\end{center}
\begin{hangparas}{1.5em}{1}
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{hangparas}o
\end{document}
```

And here is the output:

[image]

As you can see, only the first paragraph has a hanging indent. As far as I know, the hanparas environment should make all paragraphs have a hanging indent. I would love some help! Thanks.

Comment: that "o" after `\end{hangparas}` was an error when writing the question, I apologize.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a blank line before `hangparas`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hanging}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
Works Cited
\end{center}

\begin{hangparas}{1.5em}{1}
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
  The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{hangparas}

\end{document}
```

[image]